# How to place a list of attachments at the same hight as the closing?

Tags: koma-script, letters

I am writing a letter using KOMA-scripts `scrlttr2`-class. I would like to add a list of attachments at the end, and I would like that list to be at the same height as the closing, but on the right side of the document. Something like this:

```
Kind regards,                                                 Attachments:
                                                                * Attachment one
                                                                * Attachment two
My Name
```

It does not seem to be possible to put the `\closing` into a tabular. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `minipage` instead of the tabular, somthing like:

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \closing{Kind regards,}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  Attachments
   Att 1\\
   Att 2
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't try this because I thought if it doesn't work in a `tabular`, why should it work in a `minipage`? Seems I was wrong.

Comment: your solution doesn't produce, in general, the desired vertical alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Placing the `\closing` command inside a `minipage` and the Attachments into another one will *not* produce, in general, the desired alignment, as can be seen in the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \closing{Kind regards,}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  Attachments\\
   Att 1\\
   Att 2\\
   Att 3\\
   Att 4
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

which shows that the line "Kind regards," is not aligned with the "Attachments" line (using the optional argument for the `minipage`s placement won't make things any better).

One possible solution is to use the `minipage`s inside the `\closing` command:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\begin{document}

\closing{
\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
Kind regards,
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
Attachments\\
Att 1\\
Att 2\\
Att 3\\
Att 4
\end{minipage}
}}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

EDIT: and the necessary modification for the signature:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\setkomavar{signature}{\hspace*{1.5em}My Name}

\begin{document}

\closing{\raggedright
\parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
Kind regards,
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
Attachments\\
Att 1\\
Att 2\\
Att 3\\
Att 4
\end{minipage}
}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just tested this, and it does not work either, because of the way KOMA automatically puts the name below the closing. The name will now appear in the center of the page, below the last line of the attachments. You can reproduce this by adding `\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}` to the preamble.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I couldn't possible guess all the settings of your particular document. Anyway, the solution is simple, see my updated answer.

Comment: This is an extreme ugly hack, isn't it? And the vertical position of the signature will depend on the number of attachments.

Answer (score 1):

I would patch `\closing` to add the new attachment block, e.g., using a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\closing}{%
    \parbox{\@tempdima}{\raggedsignature\strut\ignorespaces
      #1\ifhmode\unskip\strut\\[\useplength{sigbeforevskip}]
        \else\vskip \useplength{sigbeforevskip}\fi
      \strut\ignorespaces
      \usekomavar{signature}\ifhmode\unskip\strut\fi}%
}{%
    \parbox[t]{\@tempdima}{\raggedsignature\strut\ignorespaces
      #1\ifhmode\unskip\strut\\[\useplength{sigbeforevskip}]
        \else\vskip \useplength{sigbeforevskip}\fi
      \strut\ignorespaces
      \usekomavar{signature}\ifhmode\unskip\strut\fi}%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \usekomavar*{attachments}\\
      \usekomavar{attachments}
    \end{tabular}
    \par
    \nobreak\vskip\baselineskip
}{}{}
\makeatother
\let\raggedsignature\raggedright

\newkomavar[Attachments]{attachments}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{attachments}{Att 1\\Att 2\\Att 3\\Att 4}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
\opening{Hello,}
\blindtext

\closing{Kind regards,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the attachment block being right aligned, you can change the `\hfill` before the `tabular`. You could even define a new pseudo-length to have the distance configurable.

Note, I've not only added the `tabular` but also changed the `\parbox` to have it top aligned.

But note, that the patch above moves down the signature (as Gonzalo's answer does too). You could avoid this by adding `\smash` (here without changes `\raggedsignature` to see this difference too):

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\closing}{%
    \parbox{\@tempdima}{\raggedsignature\strut\ignorespaces
      #1\ifhmode\unskip\strut\\[\useplength{sigbeforevskip}]
        \else\vskip \useplength{sigbeforevskip}\fi
      \strut\ignorespaces
      \usekomavar{signature}\ifhmode\unskip\strut\fi}%
}{%
    \parbox[t]{\@tempdima}{\raggedsignature\strut\ignorespaces
      #1\ifhmode\unskip\strut\\[\useplength{sigbeforevskip}]
        \else\vskip \useplength{sigbeforevskip}\fi
      \strut\ignorespaces
      \usekomavar{signature}\ifhmode\unskip\strut\fi}%
    \hfill
    \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\textbullet\enskip}l@{}}
      \multicolumn1{@{}l@{}}{\usekomavar*{attachments}}\\
      \usekomavar{attachments}
    \end{tabular}}%
    \par
    \nobreak\vskip\baselineskip
}{}{}
\makeatother

\newkomavar[Attachments]{attachments}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{signature}{It's me}
\setkomavar{attachments}{Att 1\\Att 2\\Att 3\\Att 4}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
\opening{Hello,}
\blindtext

\closing{Kind regards,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But in this case the attachments could run into the bottom margin and even below it.